# Auto call intent code, giving me issues?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.*;

public class ignitionClass {
    Intent dialI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:610-970-1218"));
    startActivity(dialI);
}
```

Now the issues I am being faced with are from Intent dialI all the way down. I think its something simple for the most part... Just I cant figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "diall all the way down" do you want the app to start dialing? If so then it won't happen for security reasons. User needs to initiate call himself, your app can just prompt the dial screen with number filled in. Otherwise malicious software can dial on paid numbers, etc.

Comment: I am trying to make a program that when run will dial home. Its just a test app to see if I can do it.

Comment: You can't, apps don't have enough rights to initiate a call (start dialing).

Comment: I think I have user permissions set up or is that a no go on the flight line as well... Note also someone told me it was not possible to make an app auto start. Maybe I'm wrong... maybe I'm right.

Comment: You (as a user) have a permission to initiate a call, app doesn't. Apps can't initiate calls on users behalf. App can have a permission to intercept calls and text messages and do something with that information, e.g. log, start audio recording, etc, but call a number is no no.